# Microsoft Azure Face API - Face detect (no result)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

While using Face detect service of Face API V1.0 I encounter no errors but no result also. I am working on c#. 
API key is valid and shows result on other codes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Code is as follows:

using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace CSHttpClientSample
{
static class Program
{
static void Main()
{
MakeRequest();
Console.WriteLine("Hit ENTER to exit...");
Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void MakeRequest()
{
var client = new HttpClient();
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

// Request headers
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "9b0bd0ce75d040769834af2339b93e1d");

// Request parameters
queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
queryString["returnFaceAttributes"] = "Age";
//var uri = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect" + queryString;
var uri = "https://eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;

// Request body
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--0MPvwvU0--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w...");

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: what does result indicates ?

Comment: Also, do not post the subscription key in forum, just replace with a sample text

Comment: You are not awaiting your `MakeRequest()` call. Worse, you are not returning anything from `MakeRequest()`. Not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: I am expecting the code to detect faces in provided image in Request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evilsnobu mentioned that if you want to get response, you need to return MakeRequest() result.

If you want to use the web image resource, you need to add it's url as post body.

Please have a  try to use the following code to get the expeceted result.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   var response = MakeRequest().Result;
   var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
 }

 static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest()
  {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "your key");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
            queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
            queryString["returnFaceAttributes"] = "Age";
            var uri = "https://eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString; //add ? before query string

            var data = new JObject
            {
                ["url"] =
                    "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/images/facefindsimilar.queryface.jpg"
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);

            return response;

        }
```

[image]

If C# SDK is possible, you could use  **Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face** to do that. For more information about how to use Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1188446/Face-Detection-and-Recognition-with-Azure-Face-API).

**Reference:**

[How to Detect Faces in Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtodetectfacesinimage)

**Update:**

If you want to use the following API

```
 https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/group
```

The faceIds is an array, please have a try to use the following code:

```
 var jArray = new JArray
   {
        "cd920c85-d05e-46e2-bb9e-2b0f67024ba2",
        "56001f6e-6c48-4a9d-800d-3cc693001197",
        "2ae34ecc-eb17-4260-a385-0db699ee17c4"
   };

 var data = new JObject
        {
           ["faceIds"] = jArray

        };
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. No result is achieved yet. I am getting an output 'The program '[5164] july26th.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).'

Comment: @AfshanAnwarAli. You could test it with my code  directly, and please replace the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key value in the code.

Comment: I am using your code exactly with my 'key' and project name 'namespace july26th'

Comment: secondly your endpoint is "https://eastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" while mine is "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0?" without detect. Does it matter?

Comment: @AfshanAnwarAli. Based on my test, `detect`  is required

Comment: It worked !! Thankyou soo much.  I just print the content Debug.WriteLine("Identified as {0}", content);

Comment: Face identification part is possible for free without any credit card subscription?

Comment: You could get more information about face api price from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/face-api/) .But the free-api will expired after a period of time.

Comment: I aam getting syntax error in request body. Please help me solving it. Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkdkV.jpg

Comment: @AfshanAnwarAli According to the https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/group. The faceIds  is array. Please see my update answer.